# Insert json log files in rethinkdb?

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

I have a log file by the name log.json.

A simple insert in rethinkdb works perfectly.

Now this json file get updated every second, how to make sure that the rethinkdb gets the new data automatically, is there a way to achieve this, or i have to simply use the API and insert into db as well as log in a file if i want to.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process that appends new entries in your json file should probably run query to insert the same entries in RethinkDB.

Or you can have a cron job that

- get the last entry saved from rethinkdb
- read your json file for new entries
- insert new entries

Comment: hmm i think the same process inserting new entries in rethingDB is the best option available.

Comment: How about if its is a log file something like Apache Logs . If we do tail -f logfile then we can see its contents as stream but how can we insert that as a stream in RethinkDb?